# React router cannot get my entry js

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Hello i have a problem with react-router, my code

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={StartPage}/>
            <Route path="/matches" component={MatchesPage} />
            <Route path="/sector/:idparam" component={SectorsPage} />

        </Route>
    </Router>
</Provider>,
app);
```

When I call **/matches** everything is OK, but when i try GET **/sector/15** app failed try to load http://localhost:8080/sector/client.min.js but normally will load from default path (/)

Webpack:

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
    devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
    entry: "./js/client.js",
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
                    plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-class-properties'],
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/src/",
        filename: "client.min.js"
    },
    plugins: debug ? [] : [
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({mangle: false, sourcemap: false}),
    ],
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: './',
        hot: true
    },
 };
```

Comment: did you try to add the publicPath property in the output : `output: { path: __dirname + "/src/", filename: "client.min.js", publicPath: '/',` }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the issue is with react router, or even webpack.  I think your issue is related to how you are requiring your client js file, although since you didn't include that section of code I cannot confirm.

It looks like you are including the script relative to your path 
(`<script src="client.min.js"></script>` *no leading slash*) instead of an absolute path (`<script src="/client.min.js"></script>`).